# Add matrices to a list

Tags: python, matrix, sage

I have this code which generates a few random matrices:

```
for i in range(5):
c = randint(1,10)
r = randint(1,10)
(Matrix(QQ,[[randint(-5,5) for x in range(c)] for y in range(r)]))
```

My question is how can I add these matrices to a list? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding things to a list can be done
using the `append` and `extend` methods of lists.

Example: create an empty list and append matrices
to it as you build them.

```
matrices = []

for _ in range(5):
    c = randint(1, 10)
    r = randint(1, 10)
    m = Matrix(QQ, [[randint(-5, 5) for _ in range(c)] for _ in range(r)]))
    matrices.append(m)
```

To build the list directly, use Python's comprehension syntax:

```
matrices = [
    Matrix(QQ, [[randint(-5, 5) for _ in range(randint(1, 10))]
                for _ in range(randint(1, 10))]))
    for _ in range(5)
]
```

One could define a random matrix function,
and use it to build a list of matrices.

```
def my_random_matrix(emax=5, rmax=10, cmax=10):
    r"""
    Return a random matrix of random size.

    The number of rows is picked at random between ``1`` and ``rmax``.
    The number of columns is picked at random between ``1`` and ``cmax``.
    The entries are integers picked at random between ``-emax`` and ``emax``.
    The matrix is returned as a matrix over ``QQ``.
    """
    r, c = randint(1, rmax), randint(1, cmax)
    return Matrix(QQ, r, c, [randint(-emax, emax) for _ in range(r * c)])

matrices = [my_random_matrix() for _ in range(5)]
```